# Declaring variables in a javascript sequence expression

Tags: javascript

I would like to know if there is a way to declare a local variable inside a sequence expression in Javascript. I want to declare the variable as a part of the sequence expression and not as a separate statement.

For example, I want to do something like this:

```js
temp = "1", var a, ++i;
```

Thanks for the help guys!

Edit -
I am trying to instrument Javascript (to find out potential DOM-based XSS)and the above code is just a snippet of the actual program. For example, I found a way to convert if statements to expressions using the ternary operator like:

```js
if (a === 2) {a = 1} else {a = 3}
```

... is converted to `a === 2 ? a = 1: a = 3;` ? I wanted to know if `var a = 2` can also be converted to an expression so that it can be added to a sequence expression.

As to why I am doing all this - I am replacing assignment statements in a JS program with a set of statements of my own. If I add in multiple statements in place of one single statement, it messes with the rest of the code. Therefore I am using a sequence expression to get around this.

For example, in a for loop like:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {}
```

I cant replace `i = 0` with  a bunch of semicolon separated statements. Thus I am trying to add in multiple statements with a sequence operator

Comment: My question is why would you want to do this?

Comment: `temp = "1", var` does not make any sense... It will throw a syntax error, saying unexpected token

Comment: what do mean??I dont see any purpose in your question.

Comment: This is just a example that I gave, I basically want to write multiple expressions as a single statement. I am re-writing Javascript to do something and it is necessary to convert statements like var a, b = 2, c; to another statement like (lhs = b, rhs = 2, lhs = rhs),..This is obviously redundant, but is a simplified version of what i am trying to do.

Comment: Why can't you just use `;`? I don't get it...

Comment: After you edit this definitely sounds like an XY problem. Why _"I am replacing assignment statements in a JS program with a set of statements of my own."_??? I think we need more context here, what's the purpose of doing that?

Comment: I am re-writing a JS program by adding in statements of my own to detect DOM based XSS. In my program logic, I am replacing each variable declaration with a bunch of statements of my own. I cant use multiple statements because in cases like for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {}, I cant replace i = 0 with a bunch of semicolon separated expressions. thus i am using a sequence operator

Comment: So you're trying to automate it? I don't see this working TBH. I mean, you could try some refactoring tools and use regex patterns to find your edit points, but edit it manually. Or am I missing the point?

Comment: Yes I am trying to automate the entire process.. Anyway thanks for your help, will try some other way to get around this problem

Comment: "If I add in multiple statements in place of one single statement, it messes with the rest of the code" - What do you mean? Could you give an example for this? There is almost certainly another and better way to refactor your code.

Comment: And in case of your for-loop: you can just put extra initialization code directly in front of it. There is no need to place it in the parentheses.

Comment: Why do you wanna do this only this way? `temp = 10; var a;++i;` does the same thing, is syntactically correct and easier to understand!

Comment: say I want to replace all assignment statements a = b with these statements; var lhs = a; var rhs = b; if(rhs == 1){};lhs = rhs;
Now take these bunch of statements and put it inside the loop case
for (var lhs = i; var rhs = 0; if(rhs == 1){}; lhs = rhs; i < 2; i++){} which is obviously a syntax error

Comment: @IcyFlame see my previous comment, I cant use multiple statements to replace i = 0 in for(i =0; i < 2; i++){}

Comment: @naini yes you can: 1) do your statements directly in front of the loop: http://jsfiddle.net/3rm4k/ or 2) write a function that you can call in the for-loop: `for(i = doSomething(); i < 2; i++){}`

Comment: @basilikum I had thought about that but again this would not work in cases like var a = this.b; and if I want to put in my instrumented statements of var lhs = a; var rhs = this.b; if(rhs == 1){}; lhs = rhs; because "this" will point to the wrong object in the function, also I want the changes to be made visible in the scope of the statement, function scoping will make the changes visible only inside the doSomething function and I do not want that.
As for putting it inside the loop, my code will get run multiple times and I do not want that. I guess I could add in checks for that though

Comment: well, yeah.. then it is correct... but you should always declare variables before starting with the loop. Though, the declaration inside the initialisation part of the loop `for(var i = 0;...;...)` is allowed, I prefer to do it outside the loop. Keeps things neat in the loop and it is easier to understand the structure of the loop this way.

Comment: @IcyFlame I agree with you, but since I am going to re-write code written by others, I have to consider this case as well. Btw it is var i not int i :P

Comment: sorry! I have given an example from C++!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apperently you want the statement `var a = this.b` to be changed into something like this:

```
var a = this.b;
var lhs = a;
var rhs = this.b;
if(rhs == 1){
}; 
lhs = rhs;
```

To achieve this, you can write a separate function:

```
function xy(){
    var a = this.b;
    var lhs = a;
    var rhs = this.b;
    if(rhs == 1){
    }; 
    lhs = rhs;
    return a;
}
```

To make this work inside of a for-loop, in a single line, you can transform it into this:

```
for (var lhs, rhs, a = (function(){var a = this.b; lhs = a; rhs = this.b; if(rhs == 1){} lhs = rhs; return a;}).apply(this, []); a < 10; a++)
```

That should basically do it. The `apply` method guarantees that `this` inside the function is the same as `this` outside the function.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I had looked at function expressions before but had not thought about using apply. Thanks :D

Comment: You could have used `call`. I also think initializing variables like this is plain terrible style, Very unreadable.

Comment: @WillemD'haeseleer what would be the difference of `call` vs. `apply` in this case, since there are no arguments to pass? And yes it is unreadable and bad style but that's what the OP asked for. So why the downvote (if you're the downvoter)?

Comment: If you use call you can omit the second argument. I guess i downvoted more because i didn't like the question, if you fix your answer i'll remove the downvote ( i can't now because it was over an hour ago )

Comment: @WillemD'haeseleer still no need for `call`. You can omit the second argument even with `apply`. I just like to have it there, because I think it makes the code more clearer, because at any time you see, that you actually pass no arguments whatsoever. Just my personal opinion and not really relevant to the question, so I'm gonna leave it as it is.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed you must begin with the `var` keyword followed by declarations and a semi-column. Then you can start your sequence.

If you really don't like it or do not want to use a semi-column (for whatever reason) you can try to make anonymous functions and use arguments as local variables :

```
(function(temp, a, i){ i=a, i++ })("1", 1)
```

So in a for loop you can do something like :

```
for (var i=function(){ /* any statement you want */; return 0 }(); i<10; i++) { /* ... */ }
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
var temp="1", a , i=0;
++i;
```

is a clean way to do it

Comment: No i would like to use only one statement to do the entire operation

Comment: you cannot do operations on a variable before initializing it. ++i or i*1 or whatever has to be after initialization. I think D'haeseller's answer suits ur purpose better

Answer (score 1):

I still don't feel like your question makes any sense but what is wrong with this:

```
var a, i = 1, temp = "1"
```

If doesn't make sense to increment a variable you only just declared, the value would always be 1 anyway if it where possible ( assuming a default value of 0 )

If you have to increment you could do this

```
var a, i = 1, temp = "1", i = i + 1
```

Still doesn't make a lot of sense tough...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mean this?

```
var temp="1",a,i=i+1;
```

I think you cannot use 'var' in any other way syntactically.